Why `emplace()` without arguments returns 0?
Below is the example code snippet:
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::optional<unsigned> check = 200;
 
    std::cout << check << std::endl;
    std::cout << check.emplace() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

In the above function, when I tried to print check (optional variable), I get the below error:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘std::optional’)
   15 |     std::cout << check << std::endl;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~
      |          |       |
      |          |       std::optional<unsigned int>
      |          std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}

and below is the result when i tried using emplace to print as check.emplace() is:
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::optional<unsigned> check = 200;
 
    // std::cout << check << std::endl;
    std::cout << check.emplace() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

result:
0


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.

The above example is just to demonstrate my issue. My actual program has std::optional<unsigned> check because it's optional with a default parameter. When a user passes a different argument, I want to pass that arg to a function which takes unsigned as a parameter.
These posts:
moving value of an optional variable, taking out value using streams and template, using optional discuss the topics as mentioned. None of them, in simple terms, explain how to print or get the value of an optional variable.
Can someone explain the above issue and what I could do to fix it?

For your specific use case, use value_or (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or).

First you have to decide what should happen if check does not contain a value.  That possibility is the entire point of std::optional and you always have to handle it.

#include <bits/stdc++.h>: Please, no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

std::cout << *check?

"and can we" Yet again: Ask 1 question. (And don't put something only in the title.) PS Why language or library designers did something is a history question, not a practical programming quesiton (& can generally only be answered by the designers). PS It is not useful to just link to other pages & say they don't help. Quote & explain how anything is relevant to asking. Don't expect readers to read entire other pages & guess what is or isn't relevant or why.

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Also I would not recommend changing the question title again and again(and with minor adjustments) when the new title is not more helpful/useful than the previous title.

@user12002570 It would be help if any recommendations or suggestions without invalidating the answers

std::optional has several methods for accessing the value it holds:
operator*
std::cout << *check << std::endl;

value()
std::cout << check.value() << std::endl;

value_or()
std::cout << check.value_or(0) << std::endl;

Just make sure you use the operator bool or has_value() method to validate the optional is holding a value before you call operator* or value() on it.

Regarding the first line:
std::cout << check << std::endl;

When converting a std::optional to its contained value, you need to handle the case where it is empty.
You can use std::optional::value_or for that.
std::optional::value_or returns either the value in the std::optional (if there is one), or if the std::optional is empty, the value passed to value_or as an argument:
std::cout << check.value_or(999) << std::endl;

This will output:
200

(The output would have been 999 in the case that the std::optional was empty)
If you are sure the optional is not empty (you can use operator bool or has_value method to check this), you can also get the value contained in it with operator* or with value method:
if (check)  // or `if (check.has_value())`
{
    std::cout << *check << std::endl;    
    std::cout << check.value() << std::endl;    
}

Regarding the second line:
std::cout << check.emplace() << std::endl;

std::optional::emplace constructs a value in the std::optional, and returns a reference to this value.
Calling emplace without any argument is constructing an unsigned in a way similar to:
unsigned a{};

This uses value-initialization and in the case of simple types like unsigned this is actually zero-initialization.
This is the reason for the 0 you see printed.
Live demo (both lines).
